# Transforming `erl_parse:abstract_form()` to `erl_syntax:syntaxTree()`

Tags: syntax, erlang

I would like to transform an `erl_parse:abstract_form()` representation into an `erl_syntax:syntaxTree()`. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

---

My main reason for wanting this transformation is to annotate AST nodes with typing information. It seems that using functions such as `erl_syntax:set_ann/2`, `erl_syntax:get_ann/1`, *etc.*, is the cleanest way to write/read custom annotations to/from `syntaxTree()` nodes. Is my understanding correct?

One worry I have is this. The [docs](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_syntax) for `erl_syntax` state that developers should assume nothing about the internal representation of `syntaxTree()`, as it could change without notice. Would this mean that pattern matching against tree nodes (like in parse transformations) is discouraged? Using the functions provided by `erl_syntax` to create AST nodes is sensible in my head. Yet, adopting `erl_syntax:type/1`, `erl_syntax:function_name/1`, *etc.*, for controlling the program flow or reading node information seems tedious and inelegant by comparison to pattern matching. Is there a better solution that I have missed?

Lastly, I've tried adding custom annotations to `abstract_form()` trees using the `erl_anno` module in lieu of using `syntaxTree()` since the latter representation is very verbose. This approach is hacky at best, however. I gather from the Erlang docs and implementation of `erl_anno` that this is not a correct way of decorating `abstract_form()` nodes with custom annotations. The only annotations allowed by `erl_anno` are `column`, `location`, `text`, `line`, `file`, `generated`, and `record`. Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

The functions in `erl_syntax` can work directly on the data structures returned by `erl_parse`. Only if you want to go in the other direction do you have to do a (lossy) conversion by calling `erl_syntax:revert()`.

A special case is if you have a list of `erl_parse` forms. This doesn't in itself work as a syntax tree, so you can't e.g. pass the list directly into `erl_syntax:type()`, but you can pass it into `erl_syntax:form_list()` and from there on it can be operated on like any other abstract syntax tree.

To make your code less verbose and use patterns to deconstruct and construct syntax trees, check out the `merl` module: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/merl

Comment: Let me show you what I'm trying to do; this may help clarify.

I'm trying to update the `anno` field of `abstract_form()` nodes. For instance,

`Var = {var,42,'MyVar'}, VarAS = erl_syntax:set_pos(Var, 66).`

The  `anno` field of `abstract_form()` nodes cannot be set using `erl_syntax:set_pos/2` as shown in this snippet. `erl_syntax:set_pos/2` creates a `#wrapper` record containing a `syntaxTree()` attribute (different from an annotation), `{attr,66,[],none}`. The `abstract_form()` `anno` in the *original* `Var` node is not updated. `erl_syntax:revert(VarAS)` returns `{var,42,'MyVar'}`.

Comment: One way of doing what I need is to deconstruct the `abstract_form()` node using `erl_syntax` (or `merl`) and rebuild it as a `syntaxTree()` node. For instance,  `Name = erl_syntax:variable_name(Var), VarAS = erl_syntax:variable(Name), VarAS0 = erl_syntax:set_pos(VarAS, 66).` Reverting the `syntaxTree()` node `VarAS0` confirms that the line number for the node `Var` is updated. `erl_syntax:revert(VarAS0)` returns `{var,66,'MyVar'}`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the above is not scalable when you need to alter arbitrary `abstract_form()` nodes. 

This is why I want to transform a list of `abstract_form()` nodes to one `syntaxTree()` node. It would spare me from having to convert from  `abstract_form()` nodes to `syntaxTree()`nodes merely to update, say, their line number as in the above comment.

The `erl_syntax:form_list()` you suggest seems to wrap the `abstract_form()` node into a `#tree` record. As far as I can tell, it does not recursively transform the `abstract_form()` nodes to `syntaxTree()` nodes.

Comment: A slightly better way I could find to achieve what I want is via the `erl_parse:map_anno/2` or `erl_parse:mapfold_anno/3` functions. For instance, `erl_parse:map_anno(fun(_) -> 66 end, Var)` returns `{var,66,'MyVar'}`. This updates the line number of all nodes in an `abstract_form()` tree. Using `erl_parse:mapfold_anno/3`, one can even track the node depth in an accumulator to change, say, the line number of the 1st or 10th node only in an `abstract_form()` tree.

Is there a better way to do this? In reality, I want to add arbitrary metadata to the `anno` in `abstract_form()`.

Comment: Thanks also for your suggestion in using `merl`. I had considered it previously but shied away from it for two main reasons. First, using `?Q(Text)` for pattern matching injects variables in the code, but editors generally (or at least the IntelliJ IDEA Erlang extension I use) do not detect pattern variables embedded in quoted `Text`. The second reason is that quoted patterns are helpful in `case` expressions. Alas, I am unable to see how they can be used in function clauses. I will keep what you suggest in mind, though I would reserve quoted string patterns mixed with code as a last resort.

Comment: I see. I think that the abstract_form() representation has evolved to have annotations as a standard feature (which they didn't previously), and that the erl_syntax:revert() function would need to be updated to understand how to transfer its own annotations back to the plain abstract form instead of discarding them as it currently does.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your reasoning.